# Manually add Startup and Shutdown events in a windows application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In my windows application project, written in vb.net, I can select the option "enable application framework". This gives me a couple of events that are useful like startup, shutdown, networkavailability and so on.

Due to a specific cause, I had to disable this feature so that I can execute some code before any forms are loaded. I implemented a standard sub main and created the first windows form from there.

To my question, are there any methods to hook into the startup and shutdown events in another way than using the "enable application framework"? I have succeeded with the networkavailability event, it was located on the networkchange class. But I cannot find the startup and shutdown events anywere. My Object browser tells me that it should be in the microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase or in the system.windows.application namespace.

Is this possible to achieve somehow?

I mean, there might be other methods for this instead of the above mentioned. But FormClosing etc. doesn't give the Global feature... Perhaps Application.Exit...

Thanks!

/Henrik

Comment: Have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: yepp, the Application.Exit function that I found comes from that class. It might work...

Comment: Application.Exit(0) or Application.ExitThread should solve it.